# Nginx permalink remove .html from URL

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, permalinks, nginx-config

I'm using multisite wordpress in NGINX server.

Now my site URL is like something http://test.com/v3/list/data.html
But I want url like http://test.com/v3/list/data

My rules in config file is like below

```
rewrite ^/v3/list/([0-9-_a-z]+?)\.html$  /index.php?list_v3=$1 last;
```

I have add rules in worpdress  like below

```
add_rule('list/([0-9-_a-z]+)\.html$', 'index.php?list_v3=$matches[1]', 'top');
```

Please help me.

Comment: location / {
    if ($request_uri ~ ^/(.*)\.html$) {
        return 302 /$1;
    }
    try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ =404;
}

Answer (score 1):

I found the bug, I forgot to remove `v3` from the rule.

```
rewrite ^/list/([0-9-_a-z]+?).html$ /index.php?list_v3=$1 last;
```

works for me.